# Activiti - Unable to acces task list from DelegateExecution.getEngineServices()

Tags: java, activiti

I have in Activti, a serviceTask with a java class which launches a class

```
<serviceTask id="Initialisation" name="Initialisation"   activiti:class="acoss.activiti.DelegateInitialisation"></serviceTask>
```

The class itself implements JavaDelegate like this

```
public class DelegateInitialisation implements JavaDelegate
{
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution de) throws Exception
    {
            String processId = de.getProcessInstanceId();
            TaskService tkService = de.getEngineServices().getTaskService();
            List<Task> ltasks = tkService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processId).list();
            for (Task task : ltasks)
            {
                    System.out.println(task.getId());
            }
   }
```

}

The problem : 
It gives me an empty task list.
It seems that the processId I get is not the "real" processInstanceId.
So I cannot get the TaskService, runtimeService, etc.

The best would be to get the processEngine current instance, but I don't see how to get it.
Thank very much you if you see a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using your query you get the task instances which are waiting for user interaction or tasks which are already completed, not all the tasks you defined in the process. In case you don't have any task which the process is waiting at or the process has passed, you get an empty list.
You need to access process definition and iterate over activities to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the [ProcessEngines](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/ProcessEngines.html) methods to find the `processEngine` instance, maybe `getProcessEngines()`.

The terms used by Activiti can be confusing.  The [Task](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/task/Task.html) interface "represents one task for a human user".  Maybe what you really want is a list of activities.  You can get these by doing something like:

```
RuntimeService runtimeService = de.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService();
String procId = de.getProcessInstanceId();
List<String> activityIds = runtimeService.getActiveActivityIds(procId);
System.out.println("Active activity IDs = " + activityIds);
```